# CSS Images, Images, and Fonts in Laravel 4 Framework

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-4

I am having some trouble with a few things with the Laravel 4 Framework.  First, to give the setup, I have an assets folder, within my public folder, that contains a folder for css called "CSS", a folder for images called "images", and a folder for fonts called "webfonts".  Here are the paths:

```
/laravel-master/public/assets/CSS

/laravel-master/public/assets/images

/laravel-master/public/assets/webfonts
```

Inside the CSS folder is my main CSS file, style.css.  I am trying to use an image as a background that I call within this CSS file.  Here is the code:

```
.banner-image{
    background: transparent url('../assets/images/8662834823_575a23516d_o.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 800px;
    min-width: 1200px;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
.banner-image {
background: url('assets/images/8662834823_575a23516d_o.jpg');
}
```

and:

```
.banner-image {
background: url('/assets/images/8662834823_575a23516d_o.jpg');
}
```

Within my view, I call this CSS with the div:

```
<div class="banner-image"></div>
```

Both of these result in the page remaining blank.  The image is not showing up, and I am not sure why.

On to the next one.  Without using CSS, I am just trying to have a simple image show up.  I have tried:

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/fanssignupsplash.png')}}">
```

and:

```
{{HTML::image('images/fanssignupsplash.png')}}
```

and:

```
{{HTML::image('assets/images/fanssignupsplash.png')}}
```

All of these result in the broken image symbol.  The image is not showing up.

Finally, in CSS again, I am trying to use fonts files that I have put in the webfonts folder mentioned above.  However, again the font is not working.  I know the CSS file is being uploaded correctly to the page, because the color changes on the text, but the font is not being applied.  Here is the CSS:

```
@font-face {

  font-family:'proxima-nova';
  src:url('/assets/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.eot');
  src:url('/assets/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),url('/assets/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.woff') format("woff"),url('/assets/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"),url('/assets/webfonts/proximanova-bold-webfont.svg#ProximaNovaBold') format("svg");
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:normal

  }
```

The view I am using is a blade file (landing.blade.php).  This is all on localhost, using MAMP.

Thank you very much for your help with all of this.  I am new to Laravel, and I have gotten all of this to work outside of a framework on a live site.  Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I stopped on your first question, first tried solution.

Shouldn't it be this :

```
.banner-image{
    background: transparent url('../images/8662834823_575a23516d_o.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    ...
}
```

See the removed "/assets"

Because if I got it well, your arborescence is like this:

- assets

  - CSS

    - style.css
  - images

    - 8662834823_575a23516d_o.jpg

For your second question, try to add a `/` at the beginning of your URL :

```
{{HTML::image('/assets/images/fanssignupsplash.png')}}
```

since I believe assets is at the root of your server.

Comment: This worked!  Awesome.  Do you have any solutions you can add for the others??

Comment: Don't mark this as an answer, I don't know anything about laravel or custom fonts imports.

Answer (score 0):

add font face in a main.blade.php:

```
  <style>
    <?php $url = asset('plugins/font/Roboto-Regular.tff') ?>
    @font-face {
        font-family: Roboto;
        src: {{$url}};
    }
  </style>
```

you can write also:

```
  <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: Roboto;
        src: {{asset('plugins/font/Roboto-Regular.tff')}};
    }
  </style>
```

then in your scss or css use:

```
body{
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

then you don´t have problems when public your app