# Using .svg with Laravel 4

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am very new to Laravel and have just been messing around. I am trying to write a route which links several image maps. One main map, which loads a map of counties, which loads a map of towns.

Typically I would load a .svg with php using include. I added an include into a `blade.php` view which loads on part of a layout. But I keep getting an `UnknownError` when I try and load the page. I also tried to use `URL::asset('assets/logo/logo_no_text.png')` to use the file as a `background-image` and a few other things.

However I do want to load it in php so that I can use CSS styling on elements of the image. I know I can do this inline in the html but it makes the code a little harder to manage.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154783/css-images-images-and-fonts-in-laravel-4-framework):

```css
.banner-image{
    background: transparent url('../images/8662834823_575a23516d_o.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    ...
}
```